# How to find the distance from each row to the nearest row that meets a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: datetime.date(2020, 8, 15),
  1: datetime.date(2020, 8, 16),
  2: datetime.date(2020, 8, 16),
  3: datetime.date(2020, 8, 17),
  4: datetime.date(2020, 8, 17),
  5: datetime.date(2020, 8, 18),
  6: datetime.date(2020, 8, 19),
  7: datetime.date(2020, 8, 19)},
 'sign_change': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1},
 'distance (desired_output)': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 0, 7: 0}})


      date      sign_change         distance (desired_output)
0  2020-08-15            0                          2
1  2020-08-16            0                          1
2  2020-08-16            0                          1
3  2020-08-17            1                          0
4  2020-08-17            1                          0
5  2020-08-18            0                          1
6  2020-08-19            1                          0
7  2020-08-19            1                          0
```

For each row, I would like to find the distance (in days) to the nearest row where sign_change == 1.
I have manually entered the desired output in the dataframe above.

Comment: Why the last row distance is `1`? Shouldn't it be `0` since the previous row has same date?

Comment: @QuangHoang good catch! It's now corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try broadcasting:

```
s = df.sign_change!=1
offset = (np.abs(df.loc[s,'date'].values[None,:] - df.loc[~s,['date']].values).min(0)
            /pd.to_timedelta('1D')
         )

df['distance'] = 0
df.loc[s,'distance'] = offset
```

Output:

```
         date  sign_change  distance (desired_output)  distance
0  2020-08-15            0                          2       2.0
1  2020-08-16            0                          1       1.0
2  2020-08-16            0                          1       1.0
3  2020-08-17            1                          0       0.0
4  2020-08-17            1                          0       0.0
5  2020-08-18            0                          1       1.0
6  2020-08-19            1                          0       0.0
7  2020-08-19            1                          0       0.0
```

Comment: I have heard you and BEN_YO use the term "broadcasting" multiple times before for pandas / numpy solutions. Can you share with me a link to explain what broadcasting is relevant to pandas/numpy?

Comment: @DavidErickson See [the official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:~:text=The%20term%20broadcasting%20describes%20how%20numpy%20treats%20arrays,that%20looping%20occurs%20in%20C%20instead%20of%20Python.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `where`, `bfill()` and `ffill()`. Essentially, `.where` the sign is `1`, you return the date, otherwise return `NaN`. From there you can `bfill` or backwards fill that date `back` to the next `1`; and you can `ffill` or forward fill that date `forward` to the next `1`. Then take the difference of the date and this `fill`'d date. Finally, `.fillna(0)` is for the last value in the dataframe.

---

Solution #1 - only looks forward for nearest date(see solution #2 for nearest date overall):

```
df['distance (desired_output)'] = ((df['date'].where(df['sign_change'] == 1).bfill() 
                                    - df['date']).dt.days).fillna(0)
df
Out[1]: 
        date  sign_change  distance (desired_output)
0 2020-08-15            0                        2.0
1 2020-08-16            0                        1.0
2 2020-08-16            0                        1.0
3 2020-08-17            1                        0.0
4 2020-08-17            1                        0.0
5 2020-08-18            0                        1.0
6 2020-08-19            1                        0.0
7 2020-08-19            0                        0.0
```

---

Solution #2 (This solution compares `ffill()` to `bfill()` series and returns the minimum or number of days to closest date regardless if before or after.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: datetime.date(2020, 8, 15),
  1: datetime.date(2020, 8, 16),
  2: datetime.date(2020, 8, 16),
  3: datetime.date(2020, 8, 17),
  4: datetime.date(2020, 8, 17),
  5: datetime.date(2020, 8, 18),
  6: datetime.date(2020, 8, 19),
  7: datetime.date(2020, 8, 19),
  8: datetime.date(2020, 8, 20),
  9: datetime.date(2020, 8, 21)},
 'sign_change': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 0},
 'distance (desired_output)': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 0, 7: 0}})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

s = (df['date'].where(df['sign_change'] == 1))
b = (s.bfill() - df['date']).dt.days
f = (s.ffill() - df['date']).dt.days.abs()
df['distance (desired_output)'] = np.where((b <= f) | (b.notnull()), b, f)
df
Out[2]: 
        date  sign_change  distance (desired_output)
0 2020-08-15            0                        2.0
1 2020-08-16            0                        1.0
2 2020-08-16            0                        1.0
3 2020-08-17            1                        0.0
4 2020-08-17            1                        0.0
5 2020-08-18            0                        1.0
6 2020-08-19            1                        0.0
7 2020-08-19            1                        0.0
8 2020-08-20            0                        1.0
9 2020-08-21            0                        2.0
```

Comment: thanks for answering! unfortunately, this fails is for distances going backwards.

Comment: @user6400946 not sure what do you mean. Is your `date` column sorted ascending? Or, is it unsorted?

Comment: Yes, it is sorted. To explain what I mean: if you add two further rows with 2 new unique dates: e.g. 2020-08-20, 2020-08-21, with no sign change, the distance will be 0,0 instead of 1,2. I can send you a longer dataframe or we can chat if you want. Thanks again

Comment: @user6400946 gotchya , thanks for clarifying. I have updated my answer for completeness which now compares forward and backwards. This was a good problem +1.